# How to render an attribute when the stack elements property has a value?

Tags: angular

I only want to show an elements attribute when the looped stack or array element has got it's optional value set. 
What is an appropriate way to handle this problem using Angular.

The code sample does the job, but does seem a bit elaborative for such a simple task.

```
  <li
    *ngFor="let linkExt of linksExternal"
  >
    <a
      href="{{linkExt.url}}"
      target="_new"
      *ngIf="linkExt.title && linkExt.title.length > 0"
      title="{{linkExt.title}}"
    >
      {{linkExt.content}}
    </a>
    <a
      href="{{linkExt.url}}"
      target="_new"
      *ngIf="!linkExt.title || linkExt.title.length == 0"
    >
      {{linkExt.content}}
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why can't the title attribute just be empty? But if you don't want it to be empty that looks like what you'd probably have to do.

Comment: It would be swell to avoid that, if there would be an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

Use linksExternal.filter to filter the array and assign it to a property, eg: filteredLinks

```js
filteredLink = linksExternal.filter(item => item.value == true)
```

Then loop the filtered version

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to show all the arrays elements. The `*ngIf` provides a clear solution to display elements or to not render these, but for attributes, there is no such thing.

Comment: You can use attribute binding syntax like attr.href =" (condition) ? 'some-link' :'nothing'"